# I am not able to use DatePickerDialog , DatePikcer view in latest M3 Compose Library?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I want to show DatePickerDialog in Compose project, and for reference I am using content provided by Android team on official Site, but when I am trying to use in project it is not resolving reference to this Composables.

I try to find solution all over the internet and for reference I usually use Android official site, here is solution provided by Android team but it is not working in my project.

[Official Android Site Url, where I find Solution but it is not working in my project](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#DatePickerDialog(kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.material3.DatePickerColors,androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogProperties,kotlin.Function1):%7E:text=DatePickerDefaults.colors.-,DatePickerDialog,-%40ExperimentalMaterial3Api%0A%40)

Comment: Which version of M3 are you using?

Comment: I think it is 1.01,    
also I am using compose bom with following material libs,
implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.01.00')
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.0.1")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The M3 `DatePicker` requires at least the M3 version [**`1.1.0-alpha04`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#1.1.0-alpha04).

The BOM in general doesn't contain the alpha releases.
The BOM `2023.01.00` has the library M3 `1.0.1`. Check the library version mapping [doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/bom/bom-mapping).

Comment: Sorry for the question. Does the M2 library also have a `DatePicker`?